# Hibernate: transfer the reverse engineered schema from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hibernate

Newbie in Hibernate.

I've an existing schema in SQL Server and I used reverse-eng wizard in netbeans to generate POJOs from the schema. Now a decision has been made to switch to MySQL. Is there a way where I can run any hibernate utility to create tables and schema in MySQL from these POJOs?

Thank you
Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SchemaExport](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/toolsetguide.html#toolsetguide-s1-8) tool . It can be used via the command line , ant task or directly use the [SchemaExport Class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html) in the java code.

Here is the example to use the SchemaExport class ,

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("your/hibernate/cfg/xml");
SchemaExport schemaExport= new SchemaExport(cfg);

/**First boolean means if print the generated  DDL script to the console
 Second boolean mean if execute the generated DDL script in the DB*/
schemaExport.create(true, true);
```

In the hibernate configuration xml , you have to specify your db connection info and your generated POJO from netbeans.